# How Can I directly open onResume() without any other callbacks of an activity when the activity is coming back from onStop()

Tags: android, launchmode

How can I directly call onResume() without any other callbacks of an activity when the activity is coming back from onStop().

Suppose I have 3 activities. The activity flow goes this way, A -> B -> C -> A.

When I click on Activity C, Activity A should be opened and directly onResume() of Activity A should be opened without any callbacks.

Comment: [Why? What for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/294714) (p.s. you can't)

Comment: It was an interview question. Even I said we cant, but he didnt agree...

Comment: You probably don't want to work there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly go to onResume() that is simply against the activity lifecycle.

But you can start from on start() without recreating that activity. Checkout android activity launch modes, further at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Why cant we make ActivityA as singleTop launch mode, as that doesnt create another instance when came back ??